# How to dynamically change facebook comments plugin url based on javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, flash, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I want to dynamically change the data-href for the fb comments plugin below based on a javascript variable.  I'm running a flash swf file and am passing the new link for data-href into the html wrapper via a javascript function.  When I do that, I want the fb comments plugin to refresh to the new data-href link.

```
<div style="float: left; padding-left:5px; min-height:500px" class="fb-comments" data-href="www.example.com" data-num-posts="20" data-width="380"></div>
```

Called javascript function passing in the new link for the comments plugin:

```
function changeCommentsUrl(newUrl){
// should refresh fb comments plugin for the "newUrl" variable
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will load the initial comments box, the script will when executed will clear the comments div wrapper and replace html5 comments box with new url.  JS SDK will then parse the new box.

JS SDK is required for this work. refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

fix for xfbml render from dom manipulation

---

```
<div id="comments">
<div style="float: left; padding-left:5px; min-height:500px" class="fb-comments" data-href="www.example.com" data-num-posts="20" data-width="380"></div>
</div>
<script>
function changeCommentsUrl(newUrl){
// should refresh fb comments plugin for the "newUrl" variable
document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML='';
parser=document.getElementById('comments');
parser.innerHTML='<div style="float: left; padding-left:5px; min-height:500px" class="fb-comments" data-href="'+newUrl+'" data-num-posts="20" data-width="380"></div>';
FB.XFBML.parse(parser);
}
</script>
```

---

user solved:

```
document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML='<div style="float: left; padding-left:5px; min-height:500px" class="fb-comments" data-href="'+link+'" data-num-posts="20" data-width="380"></div>'; 
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('comments'));
```

---

Comment: Added the code but when script executes, it clears the comments box but the new comments box doesn't appear.  I have the JS SDK loaded.

Comment: there is a bug in rendering from innerHTML, i edited in a solution at top and tested it here http://anotherfeed.com/login.php, there are 2 links on page url 1 and url 2, they will change and render the comments box.

Comment: Thanks, I had edited the code by removing the parser variable and it worked.  Looks like your edited code should work too.  document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML='<div style="float: left; padding-left:5px; min-height:500px" class="fb-comments" data-href="'+link+'" data-num-posts="20" data-width="380"></div>';
   FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('comments'));

Comment: ya it works i tested on my login page lol.  If you would mark the answer so other users may find the solutions.  I am going to edit yours into, so users can see different ways to render.

Answer (score 2):

I found the simplest and effective way to make your Facebook Comment box to recognize the individual URL of each page (particularly good for e-commerce sites).

Add this script to your top header portion of your website template (it generates de data-href value for your Comment Box div:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  jQuery("#FC").attr("data-href", window.location.href.split("?")[0]); 
</script>
```

And then on your Comment Box div, add the id for the value generated on the javascript:

```
<div id="FC" class="fb-comments" data-href="" data-width="700" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light">
```

Voilá. I dedicated so much time to crack this nut, I just had to share it for you to save some time for break! 
Cheers!