# Dynamic Facebook Share/Comments in Ember

Tags: facebook, ember.js

After trying a few different packages to help with updating meta and og tags unsuccessfully, I am exploring other options to integrate Facebook sharing or commenting onto my Ember site. But I seem to be unable to dynamically generate the `data-href` value in my HBS templates.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.whatever.com/reviews/{{model.id}}" data-width="510px" data-numposts="10"></div>
```

Whenever you access the first review, the comments load fine. But once you go to another, even though the href is updated the comment plugin no longer loads. Is there a way to incorporate this with dynamic URLs?

Comment: you just should notify addon (plugin) which parse `data-href` attriubute that value has been changed. It depends on which addon do you use

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: which plugin parse your `data-href` ? can you share jsbin?

Comment: Right now it's not a plugin parsing that attribute. It's just populating based on the model my HBS template is working through.

Comment: I see. FB doesn't allow create examples at jsint. Sense is next - you add div.fb-comments[data-href] and script convert it into block with comments. But it does it only on page load. So just check something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122633/how-to-dynamically-change-facebook-comments-plugin-url-based-on-javascript-varia

Comment: Try not update existing block, but create new one.  If it helps - we'll wrap it into ember-based solution

Comment: Those answers didn't help in this case. I am recreating the full element but still the same result. Is there a way I could put the FB code into an initializer and then inject that initializer into my route to parse the container every time?